# Hide Highcharts series through legend without having an empty space between them

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to figure out a way to hide specific series on a column chart without leaving empty spaces between when hiding.

Is there a something in Highcharts that gets rid of it? Also what's exactly causing that issue?

Edit: Here's an example (try hiding cat):

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            marginBottom: 120,
            marginLeft: 80,
            width: 500
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            tickWidth: 0,
            lineColor: "#C0D0E0",
            lineWidth: 1,
            categories: ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']
        },
        legend: {
            width: 400,
            floating: true,
            align: 'left',
            x: 70, // = marginLeft - default spacingLeft
            itemWidth: 70,
            borderWidth: 0,
            enabled: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            colorByPoint: true,
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                borderWidth: 0,
                grouping: false
            
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: "column",
            name: "dog",
            data: [{
                age: 52,
                x: 0,
                y: 52
            }]
        }, {
            type: "column",
            name: "cat",
            data: [{
                age: 12,
                x: 1,
                y: 12
            }]
        }, {
            type: "column",
            name: "bird",
            data: [{
                age: 14,
                x: 2,
                y: 14
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a something in Highcharts that gets rid of it?

Here's a demo that uses `breaks` functionality (computed automatically in `chart.events.render`) to get rid of the "unused" categories:

```
        var series = this.series,
          xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
          categories = xAxis.categories.slice(),
          categoryFlags = new Array(categories.length).fill(false), // indicates if any point has a value for category with the given index
          breaks = [],
          correspondingPoint;


        // find out which categories are 'used'
        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {

          for (var ii = 0; ii < series.length; ii++) {
            if (!series[ii].visible) {
              continue;
            }

            correspondingPoint = series[ii].data.find((point) => point.x === i);
            if (correspondingPoint) {
              categoryFlags[i] = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        // create and apply breaks
        categoryFlags.forEach(function(flag, index) {
          if (!flag) {
            breaks.push({
              from: index - 0.5,
              to: index + 0.5
            });
          }
        });

        //console.log(breaks)
        xAxis.update({
          breaks: breaks
        });
      }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fubwdm4x/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks

> Also what's exactly causing that issue?

That's the default behavior of Highcharts. Categories are just an information how to format x axis labels and position ticks. If you disable them, you'll get a 'normal' linear axis. Highcharts doesn't have any default algorithm that would find unused spaces between the data and remove them.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for and it works like a charm. Didn't know it was that complicated to fix a simple issue.